# How to return only hotel description from booking?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

How to print only description from specific hotel from booking.com

Ex:

[image: Hotel description]

I use this code but return None!

```
import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector

url = 'https://www.booking.com/hotel/eg/mediterranean-azur.html?'

response2 = requests.get(url)

if response2.ok is True:
    selector = Selector(text=response2.content)
    print(selector.xpath("//div[@class='hp__hotel-name']").get())
```

Any kind of help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.booking.com/hotel/eg/mediterranean-azur.uk.html?"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
answ = soup.find("div", {"id":"property_description_content"}).text
```